# MongoDb: How to update a field value in many documents based on the value of each field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I have many documents containing a field `description`:

```
const HelpRequestSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = HelpRequest = mongoose.model(
  "help_requests",
  HelpRequestSchema
);
```

I have written a function that encrypts strings:

```
const encrypt = function encrypt(text) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);

  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()]);

  return encrypted.toString("hex");
};
```

I would like to run that function on all existing documents in order to encrypt the all the `description` fields.

In order to do this, I will have to retrieve the description `field` value, encrypt it, and then write it back in the correspondent document.

A naive solution would be using `updateOne` or `findOneAndUpdate` with each document but this is not efficient.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: If you are using MongoDB v4.4 or higher, you use an [Update with Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html) along with `$function`.

Comment: @prasad_ there's no example where you can take the value of the field and modify it in a function and then return it and save it in the document

Comment: There are many examples for _Update with pipeline_. And there are examples for using `$function`. The official documentation has more than on example for each and Stack Overflow has many answers for _Update with pipeline_ (this feature is out for more then 2 years now)..

Comment: "Starting in MongoDB 4.2, you can use the aggregation pipeline for update operations. With the update operations, the aggregation pipeline can consist of the following stages:

$addFields $set
$project $unset
$replaceRoot $replaceWith
"

Comment: You can't use $function

Comment: _"You can't use $function"_. Are you sure? The list ($addFields $set $project...) you had provided are aggregation _stages_ that can be used with update. [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) is an aggregation _operator_ (and the documentation doesn't say anything about such restriction).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
db.help_requests.find().snapshot().forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.help_requests.update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    description: encrypt(elem.description)
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

or

```
db.help_requests.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        $set: {
                    description: encrypt($description)
                }
    ]
)
```

Comment: First one: TypeError: HelpRequest.find(...).snapshot(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: Second one: description is undefined